# Why is this program overflowing?

Tags: go, integer-overflow

I have a small golang program that calculates the `ith` fibonnaci number, however it appears to overflow for some numbers large numbers, even when the array is changed to a type of `int64`. Why is this happening?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fib(555) //prints a negative number

}

func fib(num int) {

    queue := []int{0, 1}

    for i := 0; i < num; i++ {
        next := queue[0] + queue[1]
        queue[0] = queue[1]
        queue[1] = next
    }

    fmt.Println(queue[len(queue)-1])

}
```

Comment: The 555th fibonacci number is `43516638122555047989641805373140394725407202037260729735885664398655775748034950972577909265605502785297675867877570`, it's not even close to fitting into an integer and has rolled over multiple times.

Comment: What's the largest integer value that an `int64` can cope with ? How does that compare to, say, your `fib(100)` ?  It's strange to me that you've tagged this question `integer-overflow` without (seeming to) understand what it means !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Fibonacci sequence gets very large, very fast. You need to use the [`math/big`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/) package in order to calculate integers this large. Translating your algorithm gives us:

```
queue := []*big.Int{big.NewInt(0), big.NewInt(1)}

for i := 0; i < num; i++ {
    next := new(big.Int).Add(queue[0], queue[1])
    queue[0] = queue[1]
    queue[1] = next
}
```

or more concisely:

```
for i := 0; i < num; i++ {
    queue[0].Add(queue[0], queue[1])
    queue[0], queue[1] = queue[1], queue[0]
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/udIITdDPfrY

Which will output the following number with `555` as the input:

`70411399558423479787498867358975911087747238266614004739546108921832817803452035228895708644544982403856194431208467`

(this is off by 1 from the expected 555th Fibonacci number, since it's 0 indexed)

Comment: Why does the array have a type of `*big.Int` rather than just `big.Int`?

Comment: Probably because every method on big.Int requires a pointer receiver

Answer (score 0):

Because the 555th fibonacci number is

43516638122555047989641805373140394725407202037260729735885664398655775748034950972577909265605502785297675867877570

which is much too large even for an int64.